# ShrinkWrap UnknownExtensionTypeException during WebArchive creation

Tags: java, junit4, soapui, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I want to create a full WebArchive for running Arquillian Tests using the new ShrinkWrap Feature MavenImporter (https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver).

The Scenario:

Arquillian should be integrated/extended with SoapUi to test a Spring application. There are n Endpoints exposed by the Spring application and implemented with cxf.

The test method looks like this:

```
 /*
 * Source folder for SoapUi project files
 */
@Value("${soapui.workspace}")
private String soapUiWorkspace;



/*
 * Output directory for test reports
 */
@Value("${soapUi.reports.dir}")
private String reportsOutpuDirectory;



/*
 * Comma separated list of SoapUi projects to be tested
 */
@Value("${soapUi.projects}")
private String[] projects;



/*
 * URL resource provided by Arquillian runtime
 */
@ArquillianResource
private URL serverUrl;



@Test
public void testServiceEndpoints() throws Exception {

    final SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();



    for (String project : projects) {

        runner.setProjectFile(String.format("%s%s%s", soapUiWorkspace, "/", project));

        runner.setHost(String.format("%s:%s", serverUrl.getHost(), serverUrl.getPort()));

        runner.setOutputFolder(reportsOutpuDirectory);



        LOG.info("SoapUi-Call for " + runner.getHost());



        runner.setJUnitReport(true);

        runner.setPrintReport(true);

        runner.run();

    }

}
```

My @Deployment-Method looks like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class).loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);
}
```

I'm getting right now this Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive com.bosch.mome.ws.facade.common.soapui.MarketTransparencyServiceEndpointsSoapUiTest.createDeployment()
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.UnknownExtensionTypeException.newInstance(UnknownExtensionTypeException.java:68)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.UnknownExtensionTypeExceptionDelegator.newExceptionInstance(UnknownExtensionTypeExceptionDelegator.java:37)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.findExtensionImpl(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:279)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.loadExtensionMapping(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:246)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.createFromLoadExtension(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:212)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.load(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:108)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ArchiveBase.as(ArchiveBase.java:662)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchiveFactory.create(ArchiveFactory.java:150)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap.create(ShrinkWrap.java:163)
    at com.bosch.mome.ws.facade.common.soapui.MarketTransparencyServiceEndpointsSoapUiTest.createDeployment(MarketTransparencyServiceEndpointsSoapUiTest.java:82)

Jan 19, 2015 6:29:46 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8888
```

I'm not adding the Assets separately because I'm integrating currently the junit SoapUi library and Arquillian for testing Endpoints and need to load the full Application/WebArchive.

I was looking to the ShrinkWrap javadoc but could not find a working solution/fix.

In the javadoc I read the following:

```
UnknownExtensionTypeException: Indicates that a default name cannot be generated for a given type because no extension mapping has been configured via ExtensionLoader.getExtensionFromExtensionMapping(Class)
```

But I don't know where I can exactly configure the Extension mapping. There is no tutorial or samples. Or may be I could not find them.

Does anybody have Experience with this new ShrinkWrap Feature?

Comment: Rubén, did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: @Ben Page, we decided to mock the calls because we did not have the time for further recherche. Sorry for the late reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been some time but maybe somebody finds it helpfull anyways.

I had the same problem and the cause was that i was to greedy in my pom.xml. I had the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
  <version>${version.shrinkwrap.resolvers}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Turns out the error just disappears if you use the BOM and the depchain somewhat like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <!-- Override dependency resolver with latest version.
         This must go *BEFORE* the Arquillian BOM. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${version.shrinkwrap.resolvers}</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
      <version>${version.shrinkwrap.resolvers}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <!-- your container goes here, too (for me it was arquillian-tomee-embedded) -->
</dependencies>
```

Also check out the documentation: https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/README.asciidoc

Comment: Thanks for giving a hint. We changed the approach for testing but as soon as I'll have the time for it, we will check it.